# Disable creation of Autofilter on DevExpress GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, filter, devexpress

when I fill a datatable and next I do

```
 xtraGrid.dataSource = dataTable;
```

GridView create automatically a lot of filter, for example:

```
 Column Age
 10
 33
 61
```

When I click on the filter icon in the Column, I have "10, 33, 61".
I think that this process is not so lightweight and it make longer time for GridView loads, isn't true?
I don't need autofilter, do you know if I can disable autofilter for ALL column programmatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ( DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn item in gridView1.Columns)
        item.OptionsFilter.AllowFilter = false;
```

The grid is doing a million (cpu intensive) things,i very much doubt that you'll get even 1 ms.
Plus i don't think that the filter "menu" is created with the view.It is probably created when you click the icon

Answer (score 1):

From your description I guess that you are talking about the [Column's Filter Drop-down](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1425) feature. Filter drop-down lists enable end-users to specify filter criteria for a particular column.
In a Grid View, an end-user can apply, change or remove filtering via a column's **Filter Button**. Clicking it invokes a filter drop-down list that by default contains predefined ((All), (Custom), (Blanks) and (Non Blanks)) values along with the values of items. The populating of drop-down list's items does not affects Grid's loading performance so it is not necessary to remove this feature in common cases.
Anyway, you can manage the [filter button](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument538) availability at the GridView's level via the [GridOptionsCustomization.AllowFilter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsCustomization_AllowFiltertopic) property:

```
gridView1.OptionsCustomization.AllowFilter = false;
```

If the AllowFilter property's value is `true` the visibility of these buttons for each individual column can be specified. The desired columns' [OptionsColumnFilter.AllowFilter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumnFilter_AllowFiltertopic) option should be used for this purpose:

```
column1.OptionsFilter.AllowFilter = false;
```

P.S. For more information on XtraGrid filtering, see the [Filtering Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument697) topic.

Comment: With you command I totally disable the possibility of filtering a column?

Comment: @crazyfrog2 As I have already mentioned in my answer, you can manage the column's filter-button visibility with this approach.